# CSS div not changing height to fit larger child div

Tags: html, css, web

Okay so I have one container div containing two divs which are floated left and right. The height of these child divs depends on the content inside (currently just text).

The problem is that the height of the container div is not varying correctly to fit the children in; it instead only fits the right hand div in and doesn't size for the left hand.

I have set the height of all the divs to auto. I have also tried setting the size of the larger child div to 100% however that seemed to have no effect.

The three relevant pieces of CSS are included below (I will also give a link to the website so that the rest of the CSS and HTML can be examined if required).

```
#container{
/*
The container, contains the page and the footer
*/
    height: auto;   /* this is the problem child...*/
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

#content{
/*
The container, contains the content of the webpage
*/
    height: auto;
    width: 600px;   
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}

#aside{
/*
The aside to be used for additional information
*/
    height: auto;
    width: 330px;   
    float: right;   
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Basically I want it so that the container will be the right height for the taller of the two children (but in this case it will always be the right hand one I think). However currently it seems to always match the smaller one.

A link to the website where it can be seen: http://timbrodrick.com/aboutWebsite.html
The "©2014 Tim Brodrick, info@timbrodrick.com," is part of the footer which is a div which starts at the end of the container div.

Comment: That’s what happens with floated elements – they don’t affect the height of their parent. Techniques to fight that behavior you’ll find by searching for keyword “clearfix”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a call of clearfix here. Try adding a class to both the inner div say "floaters" and use remove the float:left , right css from both the divs. Then just use display:inline-block in the floaters class.

```
#container{
/*
The container, contains the page and the footer
*/
    height: auto;   /* this is the problem child...*/
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

#content{
/*
The container, contains the content of the webpage
*/
    height: auto;
    width: 600px;   
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    /*float: left; */
}

#aside{
/*
The aside to be used for additional information
*/
    height: auto;
    width: 330px;   
   /* float: right;  */ 
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.flaoters{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To your `#footer` or `#container` rules, add `overflow:auto`. This will restore the behavior you're after which is created by the floated child.

Answer (score 1):

There is another thing you can do : 
You can add a not valid image under the aside tag like this :

```
<img src="nothing.png" height="271px" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

But as I think the first answer is the best .